# How to convert NSString intoNSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSString` which is a mathematical expression. I have operators `(+,-,*,/)` and operands `(digits from 0 to 9,integers,decimals etc)`. I want to convert this `NSString` into `NSArray`. For example if my `NSString` is "7.9999-1.234*-9.21". I want `NSArray` having elements 7.9999,-,1.234,*,-,9.21 in the same order. How can I accomplish this?

I have tried a code. It dosent work in all scenarios though. Here It is:

code:

```
NSString *str=@"7.9999-1.234*-9.21";
NSMutableArray *marray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        [marray addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *operands=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"7.9999",@"1.234",@"9.21",nil];
    NSMutableArray *operators=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-",@"*",@"-",nil];
    for(i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0;i<=([str length]-1),j<[operands count],k<[operators count],l<[marray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *element=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]];
        BOOL res=[element isEqualToString:@"+"]||[element isEqualToString:@"-"]||[element isEqualToString:@"*"]||[element isEqualToString:@"/"];
        if(res==0)
        {
            [marray replaceObjectAtIndex:l withObject:[operands objectAtIndex:j]];


        }
        else
        {
            l++;
            [marray replaceObjectAtIndex:l withObject:[operators objectAtIndex:k]];
            k++,l++,j++;

        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[marray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

Here str is the string to be converted. My array is the array obtained by converting the string str. When I execute this code I get the following on console:

```
 7.9999
 -
 1.234
 *
 <null>
 -
```

Comment: Use componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NSScanner`, scanning up to your operator characters, then when you find one, save the scanned string and then save the operator into the array and skip the operator (`setScanLocation:`). Continue doing this till you get to the end of the string (in a loop, one iteration for each operator).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray * marray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-*/"]
                    ];
```

Comment: Then you would have to loop and make ranges from the results to get the operators and then insert them into the result array.

Answer (score 0):

ThankYou @Wain and @Hinata Hyuga.I figured out a code that would work to convert any string to array with the help of your suggestions.

Here is the code

```
NSMutableArray *convArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inputString];
    NSCharacterSet *opSet=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-/*"];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:opSet];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<[inputString length];)
    {
        if([inputString characterAtIndex:i]=='+'||[inputString characterAtIndex:i]=='-'||[inputString characterAtIndex:i]=='*'||[inputString characterAtIndex:i]=='/')
        {
            [convArray addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%c",[inputString characterAtIndex:i]]];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *oprnd;
            [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:opSet intoString:&oprnd];
            [convArray addObject:oprnd];
            i=i+[inputString rangeOfString:oprnd].length;
        }
    }
    return convArray;
```