# Objective-c Basics : Convert string to operator?

Tags: objective-c, macos, math

Doing a grapher app i was wondering to know the following:

My string is equal to: 3*10; (for example)

I want my Integer variable to be equal to the mathematical result of that string directly

like : int result = my string result (as it was an operator)

I hope i was enough clear.

Which is the simplest way to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with something like this, but you need to know the format of the string:

```
    NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"3*10 = 0"];
    NSExpression * first = [(NSComparisonPredicate *) pred leftExpression];
    NSNumber * result = [first expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
    int finalResult = [result intValue];
```

Also you could use NSScanner to scan the string and extracts the number and the operators. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185553/how-to-convert-nsstring-intonsarray) thread for more info.

Comment: It says "Unable to parse.."

LOG:

2013-12-02 18:25:20.172 GraphX[1167:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2013-12-02 18:25:20.172 GraphX[1167:303] Unable to parse the format string "3*10"
.....some other log

Comment: Edited my answer, now the code works.

Comment: Amazing, that works just perfectly. Many thanks.

Last thing: why should be applied that " = 0 " after 10*3 ?

I mean, if my string is like "some operations", will I have to add at the end " = 0" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard functionality to do that. You can create your own parser to parse the string and get numbers and operators and after that you can perform calculation on this. There are also some external libraries like DDMathParser or GCMathParseryou can use.